# Make JQuery Tokeninput pre-populate search results on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, autocomplete

So here is a challenge: There are many different autocomplete JS plugins. Recently i've switched from **Chosen** (http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) to Tokeninput (http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/).
The problem is to force **Tokeninput** to show complete list of local-provided (via array) results on first click(focus) like Select dropdown in **Chosen**

Maybe there is some way to spawn keyboard event with empty string so the search result could be a complete list of items?

Answer (score 0):

After looking over the source code I don't think that's possible at the moment.

But if you know a bit of JS you can probably add the functionality yourself.

https://github.com/loopj/jquery-tokeninput/blob/master/src/jquery.tokeninput.js

You could create a `default_items` option and call the `populate_dropdown` function on first focus if it's set.

I'd be happy to look over the code and help with specific questions.